# Stuck with req.flash is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, flash, passport.js

followning is my app.js code and wherever i have put `app.use(req.flash());` it give me this error i have tried different stacks for it buts its not working

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
```

at this stage if i move routers down it give me some error of status code:1

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use(session({
  secret : 'abc',
  saveUninitialized : true,
  resave : true
}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.locals.sucess_msg = req.flash('sucess_msg');
res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
next();});
```

Comment: Use my git repo code for flash and passport local this is very organized https://github.com/sourabhkum/expressapp